# Supabase with React Full Register / Login / Account website

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I'm new to React and Full Stack, And I wanted to us Supabase as Database with Postrgree and i thought if i could make full registration form and In this case do i need to use Node, Express or something similar, can someone explain me how can i get into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do not need to implement a backend server using express or any other alternative***, Supabase is a backend as a service.

If you want to use Supabase as your auth server you can use the official Javascript Supabase package [supabase-js](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js)

You can find the docs here:

https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup

They have examples and code snippets.

Hoped I helped :)

*** for complicated unsupported thinks you will need to implement some backend server features, but for auth (signup and login) you can live without a custom backend

Comment: I would like to know more about when server is needed, and how can i be save from not showing the api on react, because its front end

Comment: You shouldn't post your API key to the world, one way to do it is by using environments variable, when you deploy your frontend code (for example using Netlify or Vercel) you can add environments variables and then access them from within your code.
This is a nice video explaining what I just said 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17UVejOw3zA

@neyeror358

Comment: Thank you @Alon